# Why windows API ActivateKeyboardLayout blocked when using KLF_SETFORPROCESS flag?

Tags: c++, windows, ime

When I called activateKeyboardLayout in my program using the KLF_SETFORPROCESS, this function will be blocked , and do not return. 
I want to know why this api be blocked , I found less document about this.

Other tips:
If I change the flag of activateKeyboardLayout  to KLF_ACTIVATE, it will return immediately。 I want to figure out why , Can someone help me?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

**KLF_ACTIVATE:**

> Prior to Windows 8: If the specified input locale identifier is not
>   already loaded, the function loads and activates the input locale
>   identifier for the current thread. Beginning in Windows 8: If the
>   specified input locale identifier is not already loaded, the function
>   loads and activates the input locale identifier for the system.

**KLF_SETFORPROCESS:**

> Prior to Windows 8: This flag is valid only with KLF_ACTIVATE.
>   Activates the specified input locale identifier for the entire process
>   **and sends the WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE message to the current thread's Focus
>   or Active window**. Typically, LoadKeyboardLayout activates an input
>   locale identifier only for the current thread. Beginning in Windows 8:
>   This flag is not used. LoadKeyboardLayout always activates an input
>   locale identifier for the entire system if the current process owns
>   the window with keyboard focus.

`ActivateKeyboardLayout` with the `KLF_SETFORPROCESS` uses `SendMessage` API call to deliver `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` window message:

> Sends the specified message to a window or windows. The SendMessage
>   function calls the window procedure for the specified window **and does**
>   **not return until the window procedure has processed the message.**

So most likely you are not handling message correctly, or calling thread does not have message processing queue altogether.

Comment: `KLF_ACTIVATE` doesn't appear to be a valid flag for ActivateKeyboardLayout() anyway.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, what do you mean?

Comment: @KHacker, the [documentation for ActivateKeyboardLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646289(v=vs.85).aspx) lists the valid flags.  `KLF_ACTIVATE` is not one of them.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/windows/desktop/ms646305(v=vs.85).aspx ) here which lists flags which has KLF_Active in it

Comment: @KHacker, yes, for LoadKeyboardLayout().  You're not *calling* LoadKeyboardLayout().  Not according to your question, anyway.  You can't randomly take a flag for one function and use it in a different one!

Comment: @HarryJohnston,Thanks， your comments help me a lot!